# Android Pay not accepting non-US delivery address

Tags: stripe-payments, android-pay

I'm using Android Pay with Stripe as the payment processor.  Everything works ok when delivery address is not required (am able to make end to end payment)....however when I set `setShippingAddressRequired()` (when creating `MaskedWalletRequest`), Android Pay is not allowing selection of non-US delivery address.  If I click "Add Delivery Address" it shows list of my (non-US) addresses but they're greyed out with "Not supported here" text shown underneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, turned out I needed to call `addAllowedCountrySpecificationsForShipping()` when creating `MaskedWalletRequest`....passing following for example

```
    ArrayList<CountrySpecification> allowedCountriesForShipping = new ArrayList<>();
    allowedCountriesForShipping.add(new CountrySpecification("US"));
    allowedCountriesForShipping.add(new CountrySpecification("IE"));
    allowedCountriesForShipping.add(new CountrySpecification("DE"));
```